# How is xkcd doing xk3d?

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d

I'm amazed by today's 3D webcomics found at [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/). How would he have done that? Would it require manually redoing every single comic or is there some way to automate it?

### Edit

The 3D comics are still available on http://xk3d.xkcd.com

Comment: I noticed vgcats did something 3d too, but it's not as widespread as xkcd's so I'd assume it was done manually there

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even notice that from the RSS feed.  Thanks for directing me to the site!

Comment: Wow, I didn't even realize they were all 3D and not just the first comic.

Comment: Should this be tagged as HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Each image is split into layers - each layer is its own PNG file and includes a lot of transparency.

All these images are nested inside a `<div>`:

```
<div id="comic">
    <!-- style attributes omitted -->
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_box.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_handle.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_bike.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_handle.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_girl.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_desk.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_mask.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_computer.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_desk_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_guy.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_computer.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_corners.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_desk.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_box.png" >
    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/880/headache_text.png" >
</div>
```

... the `<div id="comic">` is relatively positioned (or more importantly, non-statically positioned) and each image is absolutely positioned within it, as well as re-sized. As you move the mouse, some intense number crunching is done to recalculate new values for the `top` and `left` CSS properties of each image.

I wrote some more about it on my web site, and explain how to build your own simplified version from the ground up: http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/not-blog/how-is-xkcd-in-3d

The splitting of each image into layers, however, is automated, with a (April fools joke?) call for volunteers to make it better.

Answer (score 6):

It's (semi) manual, and Randall is trying to crowdsource the conversion, see [here](http://xkcd.com/xk3d/)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's using a script, [xk3d.js](http://imgs.xkcd.com/xk3d/xk3d.js), combined with an [automatic system](http://xkcd.com/xk3d/) to split the comics into layers.

This looks good on some, like the [first](http://xkcd.com/1/).  But others, like [483](http://xkcd.com/483/), really could give you a headache, due to the blotchy 3D text.

As a consequence, they're seeking volunteers to manually split them into better layers.